# ajax REST websevice with prestashop 1.6

Tags: ajax, web-services, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to search customer via prestashop webservice, but it is giving me an error of  200 success. I have activated the web service on prestashop backoffice 1.6. Below is the code I have used:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "http://monboutique.d.../api/products/6",
        datatype:"jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",

        data:{
            ws_key:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response ); // server response
        },
        error: function(xhr) {

            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem with 200 success? Your question is not actually clear, what are you trying to do and what problems are you facing? Please edit your question.

Comment: using secret key in client script? it's an interesting solution.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

this error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**